# Failed to open flutter

Tags: flutter

while running my flutter app i got this following error

E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
I/chatty  (29094): uid=10008(com.example.DarkSky) identical 2 lines
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
I/Choreographer(29094): Skipped 2 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
I/chatty  (29094): uid=10008(com.example.DarkSky) identical 11 lines
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
I/chatty  (29094): uid=10008(com.example.DarkSky) identical 29 lines
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
I/chatty  (29094): uid=10008(com.example.DarkSky) identical 2 lines
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
I/chatty  (29094): uid=10008(com.example.DarkSky) identical 6 lines
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
I/chatty  (29094): uid=10008(com.example.DarkSky) identical 24 lines
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
I/chatty  (29094): uid=10008(com.example.DarkSky) identical 39 lines
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
I/chatty  (29094): uid=10008(com.example.DarkSky) identical 23 lines
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
I/chatty  (29094): uid=10008(com.example.DarkSky) identical 6 lines
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
I/chatty  (29094): uid=10008(com.example.DarkSky) identical 6 lines
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
I/chatty  (29094): uid=10008(com.example.DarkSky) identical 56 lines
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
I/chatty  (29094): uid=10008(com.example.DarkSky) identical 9 lines
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
I/chatty  (29094): uid=10008(com.example.DarkSky) identical 225 lines
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
I/chatty  (29094): uid=10008(com.example.DarkSky) identical 16 lines
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
I/chatty  (29094): uid=10008(com.example.DarkSky) identical 8 lines
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
I/chatty  (29094): uid=10008(com.example.DarkSky) identical 1 line
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
I/chatty  (29094): uid=10008(com.example.DarkSky) identical 54 lines
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
I/chatty  (29094): uid=10008(com.example.DarkSky) identical 71 lines
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
I/chatty  (29094): uid=10008(com.example.DarkSky) identical 200 lines
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
I/chatty  (29094): uid=10008(com.example.DarkSky) identical 1 line
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
I/chatty  (29094): uid=10008(com.example.DarkSky) identical 2 lines
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
I/chatty  (29094): uid=10008(com.example.DarkSky) identical 2 lines
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
I/chatty  (29094): uid=10008(com.example.DarkSky) identical 8 lines
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
I/chatty  (29094): uid=10008(com.example.DarkSky) identical 2 lines
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
I/chatty  (29094): uid=10008(com.example.DarkSky) identical 7 lines
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
I/chatty  (29094): uid=10008(com.example.DarkSky) identical 5 lines
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
I/chatty  (29094): uid=10008(com.example.DarkSky) identical 4 lines
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
I/chatty  (29094): uid=10008(com.example.DarkSky) identical 4 lines
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
I/chatty  (29094): uid=10008(com.example.DarkSky) identical 3 lines
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
I/chatty  (29094): uid=10008(com.example.DarkSky) identical 1 line
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
I/chatty  (29094): uid=10008(com.example.DarkSky) identical 4 lines
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
I/chatty  (29094): uid=10008(com.example.DarkSky) identical 5 lines
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
I/chatty  (29094): uid=10008(com.example.DarkSky) identical 8 lines
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
I/chatty  (29094): uid=10008(com.example.DarkSky) identical 46 lines
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
I/chatty  (29094): uid=10008(com.example.DarkSky) identical 62 lines
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
I/chatty  (29094): uid=10008(com.example.DarkSky) identical 11 lines
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
I/chatty  (29094): uid=10008(com.example.DarkSky) identical 11 lines
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
I/chatty  (29094): uid=10008(com.example.DarkSky) identical 14 lines
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
I/chatty  (29094): uid=10008(com.example.DarkSky) identical 30 lines
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
I/chatty  (29094): uid=10008(com.example.DarkSky) identical 69 lines
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
I/chatty  (29094): uid=10008(com.example.DarkSky) identical 5 lines
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
I/chatty  (29094): uid=10008(com.example.DarkSky) identical 14 lines
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
I/chatty  (29094): uid=10008(com.example.DarkSky) identical 152 lines
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
I/chatty  (29094): uid=10008(com.example.DarkSky) identical 128 lines
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
I/chatty  (29094): uid=10008(com.example.DarkSky) identical 6 lines
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
I/chatty  (29094): uid=10008(com.example.DarkSky) identical 13 lines
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
I/chatty  (29094): uid=10008(com.example.DarkSky) identical 29 lines
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
E/UIFirst (29094): failed to open /proc/29094/stuck_info
I/chatty  (29094): uid=10008(com.example.DarkSky) identical 4 lines

And this gors on repeating

Application finished.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `flutter clean` in the terminal. May help.

Comment: We need to do that from root of the project folder or just from the directory?

Comment: @SanjaySingh The root I believe.